# How to prevent user's browser from showing cached version of a page?

Tags: html, caching, browser

I've made changes to a simple HTML page.
I need users to see the updated version.
Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>`

this will result in max load time per visit though

more info here [control cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)